# Convert RNASeq V2 data in cBioPortal having RSEM normalized results to TPM values

Tags: bioinformatics

How can I convert `data_mrna_seq_v2_rsem.txt` having `rsem.genes.normalized_results` file from LUSC (Lung Squamous cell carcinoma) TCGA data  found in cbioportal into TPM values?

I am expecting TPM (transcript per million) values